# Laravel 5.6 exception propagation

Tags: laravel

I have this method example in a ProofController(the controller use Exception) :

```
public function proofMethod(){
    throw new Exception();
}
```

In another controller I need to try and catch the previus Exception:

```
public function proof2() {
    try {
        $proof= new Proof();
        $proof->proofMethod();
    } catch (Exception $e){
        echo "error"
    }
}
```

I do not see echo error, but the excecution stops to the first methods and laravel debug show me "ExceptionNo message", I would to see the string error

thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass a message to the Exception

```
throw new Exception("your message");
```

and make sure you have imported the Exception class in your controller class `use Exception;`

hope this helps

Comment: thanks a lot! But the result is the same, only for the laravel debug page that show me the same exception with the message : "your message"